# What is the default way to handle sessions on browser crash

Tags: tomcat, gwt, browser, web

I want to know what is the best way to handle a usersession when a browser closes/crashes or something else.

We want to logout our user from the webapp, when he closes a tab, the browser or loss internet connection.

Thanks in advance for your hints ;)

Dominic

Answer (score 1):

By default the sessions remain at server side, without a connection to a client. There is a session timeout value to destory these sessions.

You cannot check if the user closes his browser without additional effort, i.e. a polling from JavaScript, a browser plugin or a custom client.

Comment: our client is written in GWT. So there is the possibility to use js